# Problem using the German letter "eszett" ß in theorem environment

Tags: characters, font-encodings

I have the following problem(s) using some special German letters:

I would like to keep the two lines

```
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
```

Unfortunately, the symbol ß is not displayed correctly...instead, I got warnings or error messages or mistakes...maybe, because I use ß before `\begin{document}`, where I would like to declare the names for the occuring theorems and definitions by `\newtheorem`...but if so, how to circumvent this?

I would be grateful, if anybody was able to help me get rid of these problems.

Thank you very much.

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[matrix , arrow, curve]{xy}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[pdftex]{color}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\deffootnotemark{(\thefootnotemark)}
\deffootnote{1.5em}{1em}{\textsuperscript{(\thefootnotemark)}}


\newtheoremstyle{dotless}{}{}{}{}{\bfseries}{}{\newline}{}
\theoremstyle{dotless}
\newtheorem{Proposition}{Proposition}
\setcounter{section}{1}
\numberwithin{Proposition}{section}
\newtheorem{Definition}[Proposition]{Definition}
\newtheorem{Lemma}[Proposition]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{großer Satz von Fermat}[Proposition]{großer Satz von Fermat}





\begin{document}



\section{0. Einleitung}
In dieser Arbeit untersuchen wir...

\begin{Proposition}
erhedtjhndtjhdet
\end{Proposition}

\begin{großer Satz von Fermat}
\label{großer Satz von Fermat}
blablablablabla
\end{großer Satz von Fermat}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you sure your file is coded as Latin-1 and not UTF-8? In any case it's a bad idea to use accented or special characters in an environment's name. Use `\newtheorem{grossersatz}[Proposition]{<whatever>}` or any other meaningful abbreviation; in `<whatever>` you're free to use anything you want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Special letters (accented or non ASCII in general) should not appear in the name of an environment (and use them with care also in labels).

I can understand your desire for having a clue in the document, but the environment's name is just a label and could be anything.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[matrix , arrow, curve]{xy}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\deffootnotemark{(\thefootnotemark)}
\deffootnote{1.5em}{1em}{\textsuperscript{(\thefootnotemark)}}


\newtheoremstyle{dotless}{}{}{}{}{\bfseries}{}{\newline}{}
\theoremstyle{dotless}
\newtheorem{Proposition}{Proposition}[section]
\newtheorem{Definition}[Proposition]{Definition}
\newtheorem{Lemma}[Proposition]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{grossersatz}[Proposition]{Großer Satz von Fermat}


\begin{document}



\section{Einleitung}
In dieser Arbeit untersuchen wir...

\begin{Proposition}
erhedtjhndtjhdet
\end{Proposition}

\begin{grossersatz}\label{grossersatz}
blablablablabla
\end{grossersatz}

Referenz~\ref{grossersatz}.

\end{document}
```

If you'd like to have “Großer Satz von Fermat” in the document, you can use an indirect strategy:

```
\newtheorem{inamedtheorem}[Proposition]{\thistheoremname}
\newcommand{\thistheoremname}{}
\newenvironment{namedtheorem}[1]
  {\renewcommand{\thistheoremname}{#1}\begin{inamedtheorem}}
  {\end{inamedtheorem}}
```

and use it in your document like

```
\begin{namedtheorem}{Großer Satz von Fermat}\label{grossersatz}
<statement>
\end{namedtheorem}
```

which is handier if you have several instances of named theorems.

No special characters in `\label`, however.

---

Consider switching to UTF-8, rather than Latin-1.